# Multiple Tables on PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to  read table data and display in on a table the only thing is that i am trying to read it on 2 tables. The 2 tables have the same structure and i have tried it with the code below but nothing happens.

```
$sql = "SELECT pricedatamt5.symbol_name, pricedatamt5.symbol_bid, pricedatamt5.symbol_ask, pricedatamt4.symbol_bid, pricedatamt4.symbol_ask FROM pricedatamt5 LEFT JOIN pricedatamt4 ON pricedatamt5.symbol_name = pricedatamt4.symbol_name WHERE symbol_name='".$value."'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row["symbol_date"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row["symbol_bid"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row["symbol_ask"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```

I hope you can help me with this one because i am really having a hard time especially on retrieving data from 2 tables.

Thanks...

Comment: $sql = "SELECT pricedatamt5.symbol_name, pricedatamt5.symbol_bid, pricedatamt5.symbol_ask, pricedatamt4.symbol_bid, pricedatamt4.symbol_ask FROM pricedatamt5 LEFT JOIN pricedatamt4 ON pricedatamt5.symbol_name = pricedatamt4.symbol_name WHERE pricedatamt4.symbol_name='".$value."'";  here is the problem in mysql query. you have  same fields  name in two diff. table so you have to  give table name before used it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the union your sql query will be:

```
$sql = "SELECT pricedatamt5.symbol_name, pricedatamt5.symbol_bid, pricedatamt5.symbol_ask FROM pricedatamt5 WHERE symbol_name='".$value."'"."
UNION
SELECT pricedatamt4.symbol_name, pricedatamt4.symbol_bid, pricedatamt4.symbol_ask  FROM pricedatamt4  WHERE symbol_name='".$value."'";
```

otherwise you should clarify your question.

Comment: i have tried it but i have a warning that says "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1to be resource"

Comment: that is the only error message that i get when i try running the php with the code above